# Displaying Ad In AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to display an advertisement using Greystrip in AndEngine.

I cannot figure out how this is done because it doesnt use a Layout to inflate views, but yet sprites.

i use BaseGameActivity to create my application for each scene i would like to display adds on.

In GreyStrip this is how they tell you to integrate ads in your application..

> Before adding calls in your application to GSSDK, you need to
>   incorporate the SDK into your AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following
>   in the  section, replacing 
>   with a package identifier that is unique to your application. This
>   Content Provider manages local storage of ad content, while the
>   Activity manages ad display.

```
 <provider android:name="com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider"
    android:authorities="<YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE>.AdContentProvider"
android:multiprocess="true"
android:exported="false" />
<activity android:name="com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdView"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> To initialize the Greystripe SDK, call the initialize method at
>   startup. This should be done within your application’s onCreate()
>   method. This call will spawn a background thread to initialize our
>   activity, and then return control to your app. In this background, the
>   Greystripe activity will download ads as well as any SDK updates.
>   Parameters: ctx: Your application Context instance appId: Use the
>   appId provided during app registration. Providing an invalid appId
>   will cause the SDK to display error notification ads.

```
 public static GSSDK initialize(Context ctx, String appId)
```

> To use a banner, place the following in your main.xml file:

```
<view class="com.greystripe.android.sdk.BannerView"
android:id="@+id/gsBanner"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"/>
```

> To reference the banner view in code, use findViewById, as with any
>   main.xml element:

```
BannerView myBanner = (BannerView) findViewById(R.id.gsBanner);
```

To request adds call

```
myBanner.refresh();
```

Now the problem is since i dont have an xml layout i cant figure out how i inflate the layout for the ad view?

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

Ive seen someone do it like this in a tutorial online, but how can i inflate this in andengine?

```
try {
    String applicationId = Utils.scrapeIgnoreCase(externalParams, "<param name=\"id\">", "</param>");           
    GSSDK.initialize(context, applicationId);

    BannerView myBanner = new BannerView(context);          
    myBanner.setLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
    myBanner.addListener(new GreyStripeBannerListener());           
    view.addView(myBanner);
    myBanner.refresh();
    myBanner.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What kind of layout you have? At least you have to have some sort of Linear/Relative Layouts to arrange your components on the screen. If so just create LayoutParams lp ... and then mymainview.addView(myBanner,lp); and get on with it.

Comment: With GreyStripe you use BannerView. As I have in my question. Check my update..The problem is i cant figure out how to integrate this with AndEngine

Comment: what is you onCreate() in AdView and how you set your setContentView() in there?

Comment: I think this one could be your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237346/showing-adds-in-gameplay-in-andengine-android

Comment: The last answer on the page looks like somethings i would need. How would it look as far as BannerView? You could just give me the pseudo code that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using AdMob but it should be similar.

Like @Sergey Benner referenced, you have to override `onSetContentView` in your activity, then create the `RenderSurfaceView` and your ad view manually.

First of all, create a `FrameLayout` to contain AndEngine's view and the ad view.
Add AndEngine's view and create your ad view, then set the frame layout as the content view.

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
    //Creating the parent frame layout:
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    //Creating its layout params, making it fill the screen.
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    //Creating the banner view.
    BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(this);

    //....
    //Do any initiallizations on the banner view here.
    //....

    //Creating the banner layout params. With this params, the ad will be placed in the top of the screen, middle horizontally.
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams bannerViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //Creating AndEngine's view.
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);

    //createSurfaceViewLayoutParams is an AndEngine method for creating the params for its view.
    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    //Adding the views to the frame layout.
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(bannerView, bannerViewLayoutParams);

    //Setting content view
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
}
```

Place this method in your `BaseGameActivity` class.

Comment: Jong Saves The Day..AGAIN! (= Dude your awesome. You really help me out alot. Cant thank you enough. Also in frameLayout.addView(this.mAdView, bannerViewLayoutParams);
should be frameLayout.addView(this.bannerView, bannerViewLayoutParams); correct?

Comment: Yea, I just forgot changing it (It's from a method in my game, but I used AdMob `AdView`. I'll fix it now :))

Comment: Is Your Game On The Market? I Want To Try It Out.

Comment: Here it is: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jong.angryballs. I didn't put too much effort in it (My first AndEngine game... maybe 2 weeks), but I did try to use many SDKs to learn different add-ons for games (So here we got AdMob, Facebook and Open Feint working). You should add them too, Open Feint is real cool and easy to add :)

Comment: Yeah I Actually Am In The Process of Integrating Open Feint As We Speak. Just Waiting For The Review Process To Be Complete. So I Can Test It Out In My Game. I Think it makes games WAY more competitive and drives more user interactivity.

Comment: Do you design your own graphics?

Comment: Trying to :) My cousin helped a bit with these. The graphics in that game are simple and pretty lame so every device can run it. Gameplay is far more important than graphics, imo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6892/discussion-between-coder-for-life22-and-jong)

Comment: Is there anyway i can make he BannerView layout bigger as in height and width? based on the screen size?

Comment: The banner view usually has a constant size, which is determined by the type of ad you are displaying.

Comment: //Creating AndEngine's view.
        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);     mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, //set render listener); its looking for another parameter RenderListener?

Comment: Lets talk on the chat. (The chat room you created earlier)

Comment: I am facing same issue, I posted my code here can you please suggest some solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607706/unable-to-display-game-screen-while-admob-integrated-with-andengine-google-pla

Comment: I tried your code, it compiled successfully but there is no adview when i deploy my game on device. Is there other stuff that need to be done to make adView appear apart frm above code.