# AndEngine - Admob black screen

Tags: java, android, admob, andengine

I have an AndEngine game wich subclasses from

```
public class BaseActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

}
```

The game works fine, now when I try to add Admob view to it, I learned from posters on SO to override the onSetContentView() method.

Which I do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    //Creating the parent frame layout:
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    //Creating its layout params, making it fill the screen.
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    //Creating the banner view.
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMobPubId);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    // set the layout properties
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


    // Creating AndEngine's view - Reference made
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, null);


    //createSurfaceViewLayoutParams is an AndEngine method for creating the params for its view.
    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    //Adding the views to the frame layout.
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

    //Setting content view
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
}
```

The ad gets loaded, but the screen is black. My game is gone.
The screen still registers touches (as I see in the debugger)

How come the engine is not shown in the lower view?!?!

EDIT: Finally got it working

used this code and suddenly it worked, not sure why it didn't before

```
@Override
    protected void onSetContentView() {
        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
        this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);
        final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

        //Creating the banner view.
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMobPubId);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


        final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView,surfaceViewLayoutParams);
        frameLayout.addView(adView,adViewLayoutParams);
        this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

    }
```

Comment: Oh and not to forget, I added the admob sdk, did the build path and order export , all is set and good to go... just a black screen...

Comment: just to be sure, try changing `android:id="@+id/adView"` to something like `android:id="@+id/game_adView"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you change the layout after it has been inflated. You can't add views after you already called `setContentView` and inflated the layout.

All you have to do is to create the `AdView` earlier and add it to the layout before AndEngine calls `setContentView`. You can see an example of doing so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940673/displaying-ad-in-andengine/8942168#8942168).

I'm using `FrameLayout` in this example, it's taken from my game where `FrameLayout` works the best. Your `onSetContentView` method will be simpler - all you have to do is to instatiate the `RenderSurfaceView` object and the `AdView` object, then add them to a new `LinearLayout` and call `setContentView`.

Comment: if I do that my screen goes black (i do get the ad though)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_rendersurfaceview);
```

because `R.id.game_rendersurfaceview` is declared as `org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView`

those are not apples/apples.

Personally, I would just add another field to the main LinearLayout in your XML to hold the adView.

---

I can't be real specific since it's been a few years since I used ads. You should be able to find an example of declaring an adView in XML. Will be something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView android:id="@+id/game_rendersurfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <adView decalaration here
android:id="@+id/game_adview" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Be sure and give it an `id` and then use that id in your code

```
adView layout = (adView)findViewById(R.id.game_adview);
```

Comment: Im not that aquented with java yet. How would i do that? And how do i attach the view?

Comment: I understand that but i have to attach that view to the parent view dont i?  I though i was attaching the adview to the rendersurfaceview. Or am i thinking wrong?

Comment: I would want 2 views - 1 for the RenderSurfaceView and 1 for the ad - maybe I'm the one thinking wrong. As I said, I haven't used ads in a couple of years - I think I've forgotten more than I ever knew about them. Sorry I haven't been much help - hopefully someone that is more familiar with blending AdMob and AndEngine together will come along (and then we can both learn something).

Comment: isn't the parent view as you're referring to it the LinearLayout and not the RenderSurfaceView?

Comment: I think so, i've updated the question as I tried the xml version... still can't get it to work